# Adding a navbar only for module's components

Tags: angular

I created a feature module in my angular 4 application, i want to add a navbar for all components (only) inside this module. How can i accomplish that without repeating the same code of the navbar in every component ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a "shell" component with only your navbar and a router outlet. Then route your feature module components to that router outlet.

Shell component template:

```
<pm-menu></pm-menu>

<div class='container'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Route configuration:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: '',
            component: ShellComponent,
            children: [
                { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
                { path: 'customers', component: CustomerComponent },
                { path: 'products', component: ProductComponent },
                { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
            ]
        },
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ])
```

Comment: I've been searching for this answer for days thank you very much for the concise answer and straight forward example.